# Why is my code not thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, event-dispatch-thread

I'm creating a game where levels can be loaded from a file. This is done on a separate thread, while everything else is done on the Event Dispatch Thread.

I tested the code by loading from a really large test file, and it turns out that the Event Dispatch Thread on occasions is unresponsive while the level is being loaded.

I can't seem to figure out the cause. Here's some of my code:

```
public class LevelSelectionWrapper extends GamePanel {
    ...
    private JList list;
    private File[] files;
    ...
    //Lock object for synchronization
    private Object lock = new Object();
    //Runnable for loading levels from files on a separate thread
    private Runnable loader = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(lock) {
                //Load levels from files
                List<Level> levels = LevelLoader.load(files); // <-------------
                ...
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ListUpdater());
            }
        }
    };
    ...
    private void createOpenFileButton(Container container) {
        final JFileChooser fc = ...
        ...
        //Create open button
        JButton openButton = new JButton("Open file");
        openButton.setFocusable(false);
        openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(LevelSelectionWrapper.this);
                if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    synchronized(lock) { files = fc.getSelectedFiles(); }
                    //Load files on separate thread
                    new Thread(loader).start(); // <-------------
                }
            }
        });
        container.add(openButton);
    }
}
```

I've added two arrows to the code:

- The first one is the time consuming method (when the files are really large). On occasions, the Event Dispatch Thread is unresponsive while this code is running.
- The last one is where the runnable is invoked.

Comment: What is the `syncronized(lock)` for in this context?  It seems like a bad/unnecessary use of syncronization to me.  Better, for instance, to get the list of files locally, construct a copy, and pass the copy off to the loader, than to use  shared object that you then have to lock on.  If I'm misunderstanding it's purpose, perhaps you could elaborate on it.

Comment: Is it only the EDT in this one app that is unresponsive, or the rest of the system, too?

Comment: @Ralf: I'm only using two threads, the EDT and the worker thread. The EDT is unresponsive until the worker thread is done.

Comment: First of all, "thread safe" normally refers to a body of code which can be used by different threads simultaneously without error, not to a multi-threaded application which is not switching between threads in the way desired.

An unresponsive UI, if due to the way you are handling the EDT, is usually the result of invoking some compute-intensive operation on the EDT.  

What operation(s) cause the UI to become unresponsive?  What are the Swing events that occur just before that(those) time(s)?

Comment: Lock the system when UI is running.

Comment: is there any other place where you `synchronize` on `lock`?

Comment: @Dimo: The lock is mainly to prevent the files variable from changing while the worker thread is reading it. But yeah, I could probably do that.

Comment: @Ralf: There are three places. Two of them are in the code above, and the third is in the ListUpdater. A runnable that isn't invoked until after the loading is done.

Comment: @Rcook: No compute-intensive operations are invoked on the EDT, and it is only unresponsive occasionally. It must be waiting or blocked for some reason.

Comment: Try some time measurements between just before entering synchronized and right after entry. Log the time if more than 1ms or so. Maybe that helps to find why it locks up **occasionly**.

Comment: post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: +1 to Ralf's comment by the way. A `paintComponent` method had also synchronized on lock, which I had forgotten about. That's the reason why the EDT would block occasionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely suggest getting rid of that `lock` object (and the associated dependencies).  Get the list of files inside `actionPerformed()` and construct a copy to pass off to your runnable.  Avoid using instance variables like `files` like you currently are, as those are being shared across threads unnecessarily.

These `synchronized` blocks are the most likely culprit to me.  If that doesn't resolve your issue, I'd suggest adding some `System.out.println()` calls around the areas you think are blocking to try to see exactly which call(s) are taking so long.

Also consider using [SwingWorkers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) rather than constructing a new thread yourself.  That could save you a few cycles of thread-startup time in the EDT.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was of great help! I decided to use `SwingWorkers`, and so far, the Event Dispatch Thread hasn't become unresponsive. Also, since the lock is gone, I can now load other levels while there are already levels loading.

Comment: Nice!  `synchronized` blocks are useful tools, but there are often many cleaner and more elegant solutions to dealing with concurrency.  Use them sparingly, and wherever possible limit data to one thread at a time.